# d'Arsonval Ammeters in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am working through a circuit book on my own.  This is not for any school homework.  I have the following problem which I can't seem to wrap my head around.

```
Two d'Arsonval ammeters are connected in parallel.  Ammeter 1 uses a 2 
mA, 100 mV movement and has a full-scale reading of 25 mA.  Ammeter 2 
uses a 1 mA, 25 mV movement and has a full-scale reading of 10 mA.  
What is the largest current these parallel-connected ammeters can 
read?
```

Taking each ammeter alone I can calculate the shunt resistor.  But when you put them in parallel I am not sure what to do.  They have two different voltage ratings and putting those in parallel is confusing.  Can someone help?

Comment: If you calculate the voltage-drop for each meter at its full-scale reading, you'll then see which of the 2 is the limiting factor (whichever is smaller). Since they'll be wired in parallel, that same voltage will be across the other meter. So what will the other meter's current be? You have all the necessary info to calculate this - go for it ...

Comment: Thank you.  I thought that you would use one as the limiting factor and proceed.  Thanks again